# How to remove text contents in markers in basic jquery slider bjqs.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the [basic jQuery slider bjqs.js plugin](http://basic-slider.com/) ([Github](https://github.com/jcobb/basic-jquery-slider)).

How can I remove or modify text contents in markers? It's not possible via the default plugin option. Is it possible to modify something inside plugin scripts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm find a solution, for release 1.3:

In bjqs-1.3.js you can change this string on row 482:

> `var marker = $('<li><a href="#">'+ slidenum +'</a></li> ');`
>
> where **slidenum** in number of slide

or on bjqs-1.3.min.js you can change this string:

> ```
> var o=e('< li >< a href="#" >'+i+"< /a >< /li >");
> ```
>
> where i is a number of slide.

depending on what you use if minified file or not.

Comment: I think that is not the solution, but now I have found only this way.